# Pc consumes 13W also when PSU is switched off

Tags: hardware-failure, power-consumption

I noticed that my pc consumes 13W also when PSU is switched off.

So I opened the PSU and I found a yellow box directly connected with the plug's socket, before the on-off button.

This yellow box has connected two little cables and a resistor, and it's approximately 2x2x1 cm.

I removed it and pc seems to work properly. What could it be?

Comment: Do you mean 13W? Modern PSU's (modern PC's), in order for you to actually turn them on (amongst other things) have a [*vampiric load*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standby_power).

Comment: Yes I think W is proper. With pc shutted off: 26W. With pc shutted off and PSU button set to 0: 13W. So 13W were consumed by the yellow box.
 I'd like to know if it serves something...

Comment: @T30 So update your question and correct your mistake.  Of course the behavior you describe is normal.

Comment: Can you take a picture of what you are referring to?

Comment: Asap i'll add a photo.

Comment: I would just get a new power supply instead of randomly removing parts, and don't get a generic unit.  The part was there for a reason and removing it could damage something.

Comment: "I noticed that my pc consumes 13W also when PSU is switched off." How did you come to that conclusion? Is that 13VA or 13W cos0, because it could well be 13 VAR, if it is indeed a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow box is likely a capacitor for filtering electromagnetic interference (X capacitor).

It can't consume 13W because it does not have large enough surface area to dissipate 13W of heat and does not have a heatsink (so it would burn if it really consumed that much) and capacitors should not consume energy.

The resistor is used to discharge the potentially dangerous charge in the capacitor after disconnecting power, it consumes some power but it should be only a fraction of watt (otherwise it would burn).

**Update:**

Removing X capacitor may cause instability or earlier failure of PC power supply. It may also negatively affect other devices due to more interference going from the PC to power lines.

Comment: But if it's really an X capacitor, is it necessary? What kind of problem can I have, after removing it?